# LeetCode 212: Word Search II

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++17

I'm posting my code for a LeetCode problem. If you'd like to review, please do so. Thank you for your time!

#### Problem

> Given a 2D board and a list of words from the dictionary, find all
> words in the board.
>
> Each word must be constructed from letters of sequentially adjacent
> cell, where "adjacent" cells are those horizontally or vertically
> neighboring. The same letter cell may not be used more than once in a
> word.
>
> #### Example:
>
> ```
> Input:  board = [   
> ['o','a','a','n'],   
> ['e','t','a','e'],  
> ['i','h','k','r'],   
> ['i','f','l','v'] 
> ] 
> words =
> ["oath","pea","eat","rain"]
>
> Output: ["eat","oath"]
> ```
>
> Note:
>
> - All inputs are consist of lowercase letters a-z.
> - The values of words are distinct.

#### Code

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>

class Solution {
    static constexpr unsigned int A_LOWERCASE = 'a';
    static constexpr unsigned int ALPHABET_SIZE = 26;

private:
    class TrieNode {
    public:
        std::vector<TrieNode *> children;
        bool is_word;

        TrieNode() {
            is_word = false;
            children = std::vector<TrieNode *>(ALPHABET_SIZE, NULL);
        }
    };

    class Trie {
    public:
        TrieNode *get_parent() {
            return parent;
        }

        Trie(const std::vector<std::string> &words) {
            parent = new TrieNode();

            for (unsigned int index = 0; index < words.size(); index++) {
                set_word(words[index]);
            }
        }

        void set_word(const std::string &word) {
            TrieNode *curr = parent;

            for (unsigned int length = 0; length < word.size(); length++) {
                unsigned int index = word[length] - A_LOWERCASE;

                if (curr->children[index] == NULL) {
                    curr->children[index] = new TrieNode();
                }

                curr = curr->children[index];
            }

            curr->is_word = true;
        }

    private:
        TrieNode *parent;

    };

public:
    std::vector<std::string> findWords(std::vector<std::vector<char>> &board, std::vector<std::string> &words) {
        Trie *trie = new Trie(words);
        TrieNode *parent = trie->get_parent();
        std::set<std::string> found_words;

        for (unsigned int row = 0; row < board.size(); row++) {
            for (unsigned int col = 0; col < board[0].size(); col++) {
                depth_first_search(board, row, col, parent, "", found_words);
            }
        }

        std::vector<std::string> structured_found_words;

        for (const auto found_word : found_words) {
            structured_found_words.push_back(found_word);
        }

        return structured_found_words;
    }

private:

    static void depth_first_search(std::vector<std::vector<char>> &board, const unsigned int row, const unsigned int col, const TrieNode *parent, std::string word, std::set<std::string> &structured_found_words) {
        if (row < 0 || row >= board.size() || col < 0 || col >= board[0].size() || board[row][col] == ' ') {
            return;
        }

        if (parent->children[board[row][col] - A_LOWERCASE] != NULL) {
            word = word + board[row][col];
            parent = parent->children[board[row][col] - A_LOWERCASE];

            if (parent->is_word) {
                structured_found_words.insert(word);
            }

            char alphabet = board[row][col];
            board[row][col] = ' ';
            depth_first_search(board, row + 1, col, parent, word, structured_found_words);
            depth_first_search(board, row - 1, col, parent, word, structured_found_words);
            depth_first_search(board, row, col + 1, parent, word, structured_found_words);
            depth_first_search(board, row, col - 1, parent, word, structured_found_words);
            board[row][col] = alphabet;
        }
    };
};
```

#### Reference

LeetCode has a template for answering questions. There is usually a class named `Solution` with one or more `public` functions which we are not allowed to rename. For this question, the template is:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> findWords(vector<vector<char>>& board, vector<string>& words) {
        
    }
};
```

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-search-ii/)
- [Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-search-ii/solution/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-search-ii/discuss/)
- [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Avoid defining trivial constants

While it is good practice to give some constants that are used throughout the code a nice descriptive name, `A_LOWERCASE` is a case of a trivial constant where it is actually detrimental to define it. The reason is that `A_LOWERCASE` describes exactly its value, instead of what the value stands for. If you would call it `FIRST_LETTER_OF_THE_ALPHABET`, it would be a better name (although obviously a bit too long for comfort). But, everyone already knows that `'a'` is the first letter. It's as trivial as the numbers 0 and 1, and you wouldn't write:

```
static constexpr int ZERO = 0;
static constexpr int ONE = 1;

for (int i = ZERO; i < ...; i += ONE) {
    ...
}
```

Another issue with such constants is that if you ever write `constexpr unsigned int A_LOWERCASE = 'b'`, the compiler won't complain, the code won't work as expected, and someone reading the code will probably not think that `A_LOWERCASE` might be anything other than `'a'` and thus have a hard time finding the issue.

## Move `TrieNode` inside `Trie`

Since `TrieNode` is an implementation detail of `Trie`, it should be moved inside it:

```
class Trie {
public:
    class Node {
        ...
    };

    Node *get_root() {
        return root;
    }

    ...

private:
    Node *root;
};
```

Also note that the parent of a tree is not a node. The correct term to use here is "root".

## Use `std::array` to store trie node children

Instead of a fixed size vector, you should use `std::array`. It avoids a level of indirection:

```
class Trie {
    class Node {
        std::array<Node *, 26> children;
        ...
```

## Prefer using default member initializers

This avoids having to write a constructor in some cases, and is especially useful to avoid repeating yourself when a class has multiple constructors. In this case you can write:

```
class Trie {
    class Node {
        std::array<Node *, 26> children{};
        bool is_word{false};
    };
    ...
};
```

## Avoid `new` when you can just declare a value

In the constructor of `Trie` you always allocate a new `Trie::Node`. This is unnecessary, you can just write:

```
class Trie {
public:
    class Node {...};

    Node *get_root() {
        return &root;
    }

    ...
private:
    Node root;
};
```

Similarly, in `findWords()`, you can just write:

```
std::vector<std::string> findWords(std::vector<std::vector<char>> &board, std::vector<std::string> &words) {
    Trie words;
    ...
}
```

## Use `std::unique_ptr` to manage memory

Avoid calling `new` and `delete` manually. It is easy to make mistakes and cause a memory leak. I don't see any call to `delete` in your code! A [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) will manage memory for you and delete it automatically once it goes out of scope. Here is how to use it:

```
class Trie {
    class Node {
        std::array<std::unique_ptr<Node>, 26> children;
        ...
    };

    ...

    void set_word(const std::string &word) {
        Node *curr = get_root();

        for (...) {
            ...

            if (!curr->children[index]) {
                curr->children[index] = std::make_unique<Node>();
            }
        
            curr = curr->children[index].get();
         }

         curr->is_word = true;
    }

    ...
};
```

## Prefer using range-for

When iterating over containers (this includes iterating over the characters in a `std::string`), and you don't need to manipulate the iterator itself but just want to see the values, use a range-for loop. For example in the constructor of `Trie`:

```
Trie(const std::vector<std::string> &words) {
    for (auto &word: words) {
        set_word(word);
    }
}
```

And in `set_word()`:

```
for (auto letter: word) {
    unsigned int index = letter - 'a';
    ...
}
```

## Simplify return value of `findWords()`

Instead of creating a temporary `std::vector` and copying elements manually from `found_words`, you can make use of the fact that `std::vector` has a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that can copy elements from another container for you, and use brace-initialization in the `return` statement:

```
std::vector<std::string> findWords(std::vector<std::vector<char>> &board, std::vector<std::string> &words) {
    std::set<std::string> found_words;
    ...
    return {found_words.begin(), found_words.end()};
}
```